# Passing table name to MySQL procedure then ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, dynamic, parameter-passing

I have passed a table name to a MySQL procedure and can access the data with no problem.

However if I add an "ORDER BY" to the procedure then it fails

The procedure I'm trying to add is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxx` PROCEDURE `get_data`(IN `tbl` CHAR(64))
BEGIN
SET @s := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tbl , 'ORDER BY date');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Without the text *, 'ORDER BY date'* the procedure returns the correct result (the full table's data)

With the "ORDER BY ..." I get the error:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY date' at line 1

Comment: There is no space between table name and ORDER by clause in your string

Comment: So simple! And I could have sworn I'd tried with a space.

Many thanks.